# Plotting Two Ellipses with same Foci in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, ellipse, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to plot two different ellipses in Matlab with the same foci. Essentially I am plotting the elliptical orbit before and after an impulse maneuver.

The first (before maneuver) ellipse will always be in-line with the x-axis, whereas the second ellipse (after maneuver) will be at an angle above/below the x-axis (The second one will have a different major/minor axis and eccentricity as well).

In order to save space, the code for plotting one ellipse will be the same as the second ellipse, so I'll only show my code here for plotting one ellipse.

The problem is that it plots from the center of the grid, and not the foci.

```
 Re = 6378.136;    %km
 e  = .65;
 x1 = -4.4*Re;     %-a
 x2 =  4.4*Re;     % a
 y1 = 0;
 y2 = 0;

 a = 1/2*sqrt((x2-x1)^2+(y2-y1)^2);
 b = a*sqrt(1-e^2);
 t = linspace(0,2*pi);

 X = a*cos(t);
 Y = b*sin(t);

 w = atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1);

 x = (x1+x2)/2 + X*cos(w) - Y*sin(w);
 y = (y1+y2)/2 + X*sin(w) + Y*cos(w);

 plot(x,y,'b')
 axis equal
 grid on
 hold on
```

I'm sure it's something simple but I can't seem to figure it out.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: David helped solve this issue, thank you.

Comment: "The problem is that it plots from the center of the grid, and not the foci." What do you mean by this? Since x1+x2=0, your ellipse will be centred around the origin, is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, thank you. I knew it was something dumb. I know have x1 = -(a+a*e); x2 =  (a-a*e). This gives me the origin to be centered on the right focal point. I appreciate your help, thanks.